# What is the assign operator in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'd like to know if there is a separate assign operator like "=" in tikz for assigning results from certain operations. I know \pgfmathparse can do it through \pgfmathresult, but it seems too complicated.

Comment: I think you are looking for the library `tikzmath`. It allows to declare variables and operate with them, which later can be used called from almost everywhere on the document

Comment: For calculations that are to be used for one specific path, there is also the `let` operation, described in chapter 14.15 *The Let Operation* of the manual.